# Converting PHP assoc array to json object

Tags: javascript, php

I have an assoc array in PHP:

```
foreach ($result as $value) {   
    $x++;
    $data += array("nds" => array($x => $x), "eds" => array(), "an" => array($x => $this->model->getLng($value)));
}
```

I send this array to a JS file and it prints like below:

```
{"nds":{"1":1},"eds":[],"an":{"1":[45.4423073,-75.7979993]}}
```

However, I cannot reach `nds` because this returns undefined:

```
console.log(data.nds);
```

Answer (score 1):

PHP is just sending a string to the JS file. You would first need to set a variable equal to that string:

```
<script>
  var json = '<?= $data; ?>';
</script>
```

Now we have a JS variable `json`, but it needs to be converted to an object to reference the `nds` property. We can do that with [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse):

```
<script>
  var json = '<?= $data; ?>';
  var data = JSON.parse(json);

  console.log(data.nds); // Object {1: 1}
</script>
```

---

@RobM made a good point that we don't even need to parse this as a string and can just set the variable as the JSON dump:

```
<script>
  var data = <?= $data; ?>;
  console.log(data.nds); // Object {1: 1}
</script>
```

This still requires you to pass the JSON data (`{ "nds": { "1": 1 }, "eds": [], "an": { "1": [ 45.4423073, -75.7979993 ] } }`) from your PHP script into a JS variable.

Comment: in this case I get: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Comment: This (`var json = '<?= $data; ?>';`) is not necessarily valid, how have you outputted the JSON string from PHP in your current code? My code assumes that the PHP variable `$data` is passed to your JS code.

Comment: {
    "nds": {
        "1": 1
    },
    "eds": [],
    "an": {
        "1": [
            45.4423073,
            -75.7979993
        ]
    }
}

Comment: For my above code to work, you need to have the following line of JS: `var json = '{ "nds": { "1": 1 }, "eds": [], "an": { "1": [ 45.4423073, -75.7979993 ] } }';`. Depending on your set up, this should be pretty easy. But we can't do any JS parsing until the string is a JS variable.

Comment: Why not just omit the quotes? Then you won't have to `JSON.parse`

Comment: why I can simply access it like that ? data.nds[0 ] It says: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined. I think It's the same reason.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the jQuery JSON parser or the standard Javascript JSON parser:

```
var data = '{"nds":{"1":1},"eds":[],"an":{"1":[45.4423073,-75.7979993]}}';

var d = $.parseJSON(data);  // jQuery
console.log(d['nds']);

var j = JSON.parse(data);   // Javascript
console.log(j['nds']);
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/bb7ak6L5/

Comment: Is it possible to make it accessible for something like that console.log(j.nds[0]);